# How to derive a formula?

Tags: math, formula, game-physics

I have two 5x5 diamond grids,

`Grid1`: **Y** values are,

```
    0
   1 1
  2 2 2
 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4
 5 5 5 5
  6 6 6
   7 7
    8
```

`Grid2`: **X** values are,

```
    0
   0 1
  0 1 2
 0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
 0 1 2 3
  0 1 2
   0 1
    0
```

I need to derive a formula to get `Grid3` values related to `X`, `Y`, and `gridSize`. expecting the below values in `Grid3` (index values),

```
        00
      01  02
    03  04  05
  06  07  08  09
10  11  12  13  14
  15  16  17  18 
    19  20  21
     22   23
        24
```

What could be the formula which can be used to get `Grid3` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a function `getindex(x,y,size)` returning the index, the first thing to notice is that because the index values increase from left to right first, the following identity always holds: `getindex(x+1,y,size) = getindex(x,y,size)+1`.

So we have

```
getindex(x,y,size): return x+[something involving only y and size]
```

Let's look at the index values for x=0.  They start off as 0,1,3,6,10... for y=0,1,2.... These are the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) 0, 1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4... and there's a closed-form solution `y*(y+1)/2`.

So our function, for the top half of the grid, looks like:

```
getindex(x,y,size): return x+y*(y+1)/2
```

When are we in the bottom half? When `y>size`.  What do we do then? Count triangular numbers backwards from the bottom line.  There are a total of `(size*2-1)` lines, so to flip the y coordinate we can replace y by `(size*2-1)-y`.  Note that when y *equals* size we're in both the top and bottom half as far as this calculation is concerned.

Our function so far:

```
getindex(x,y,size): return x+((y<size) ? y*(y+1)/2 : size*size-(size*2-1-y)*(size*2-1-y+1)/2)
```

We should probably check for values that aren't actually in the grid.  When are values not in the grid?  When x or y is less than zero (off the top or left), or `x>y` (off the right in the top half), or `x>=(size*2-1)-y` (off the right in the bottom half) or `y>size*2-1` (off the bottom).

So here we go:

```
function getindex(x,y,size):
     if (x<0) return "off to the left"
     if (y<0) return "off to the top"
     if (x>y) return "off to the right (top half)"
     if (x>=(size*2-1-y)) return "off to the right (bottom half)"
     if (y>size*2-1) return "off the bottom"
     
     return x+((y<size) ? y*(y+1)/2 : size*size-(size*2-1-y)*(size*2-1-y+1)/2)
```

Test it:

```
size = 5
counts = []
for (y in 0..10):
  for (x in 0..10):
     index = getindex (x, y, size)
     print x, y, index
     if index is OK:
       counts[index]++
```

Now check that each grid value was produced precisely once:

```
assert (keys(counts) == size*size)
for i in (0..size*size-1):
   assert (counts[i] == 1)
```

Writing a function to go in the reverse direction is left as an exercise :)

Comment: The top half of the values are correct (until the 5th column). The bottom half values are incorrect.

Comment: Paste error, fixed.